# Is my simple Lua script hanging on the first task?

Tags: lua

I have the following code that I am not able to test very well due to the testing window being so short. It is for an iPhone autotouch script that will scan a coordinate for a color and tap when the color changes to black. I added a second component to the script which functions similarly, it detects a color on the screen then taps on a specified coordinate. Is the code formatted in a way where when the first color is detected and the tap occurs, the code advances to the second portion of the code?

colorone is the variable for the first page, and colortwo is the variable for the second page (the page displayed after the first colorone button is tapped).

Thank you in advance

```
local colorone = getColor(165, 1566)
local colortwo = getColor(652, 2301)

repeat
    colortwo = getColor(652, 2301)
until( colortwo == 0 )
tap(652, 2301);

repeat
   colorone = getColor(165, 1566)
until( colorone == 0 )
tap(920, 1688);
```

Comment: If you want `colorone` checked first it needs to come before your repeat loop where you check `colortwo`.

Comment: Colortwo should be checked first, just messed up the wording of the variables

Comment: Well, until it finds `colortwo` it won't proceed to `colorone`, because of the while loop. you first have to trigger colortwo action before it would proceed to colorone.
If this does not fix your problem, just check whenever tap function is being fired.

Comment: Put both in a single loop: `repeat; if colorone ~= 0 then colorone = getColor(165, 1566) end; if colortwo ~= 0 then colortwo = getColor(652, 2301) end; until(colorone == 0 and colortwo == 0)`